# Color for first option in select will not change.

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

```
<select class="form-control" id="widgets">
            <option class="text-muted" style="color: grey;">Choose an option</option>
</select>
```

I have one option in my select and I want to change the color of the text to grey.  I have tried Bootstrap text_muted or css color:grey.  Neither work.  What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Add .text-muted into css and color:grey; works fine for me?

Answer (score 1):

Looks fine to me, maybe you aren't noticing it because of the highlight on the single option see this change:

```html
<select class="form-control" id="widgets">
    <option class="text-muted" style="color: white;">Choose an option</option>
    <option class="text-muted" style="color: grey;">Choose an option</option>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0):

Hello it seems not onlu bootstap adjusting color for  but also default browser applies its style. Therefore you may act 2 ways: strict selector pointing e.g.: `select>option.text-muted{color:red}`.And the second one is to remove the double assigning of the color in bootstrap and clear browser cache after each modification of your code . It saves  a lot of time. Color adjusted: https://jsfiddle.net/0p2dk5ee/.